# cin.getline() is removing the first letting of my input in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

When I use this following code, the first string input is displayed correctly, but every string input afterwards is missing the first letter.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
    //declare arrays
    string cd_Name[20] = {""};
    string cd_Artist[20]= {""};

    //declare variables
    int numCD = 0;

    cout << "Enter number of CD's: ";
    cin >> numCD;
    if (numCD <= 20)
    {   
        for (int x = 0; x < numCD; x++)
        {
            cout << "Enter name of CD " << x + 1 << ": ";
            cin >> cd_Name[x];
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, cd_Name[x]);
            cout << "Enter the artist of " << cd_Name[x] << ": ";
            cin.get();
            getline(cin, cd_Artist[x]);
            cout << endl;
        }//end of for loop

        cout << "CD Names                         Artists" << endl;
        cout << "========                         =========" << endl;

        for (int x = 0; x < numCD; x++)
        {
            cout << cd_Name[x] <<"                "<< cd_Artist[x] << endl;
        }//end of for loop
    }
    else    
        cout << "You can only enter a Max of 20 CD's" << endl;
    //end of if

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
 }//end of main function
```

An example of the output is shown below:

```
Enter the number of CD's: 3
Enter name of CD 1: The Battle of Los Angeles
Enter the artist of The Battle of Los Angeles: Rage Against the Machine

Enter name of CD 2: So Far So Good
Enter the artist of o Far So Good: Brian Adams

Enter name of CD 3: Amarte es un Placer
Enter the artist of marte es un Placer: Luis Miguel

CD Names                              Artists
=========                            ==========
The Battle of Los Angeles            ise Against the Machine
o Far So Good                        rian Adams
marte es un Placer                   uis Miguel
```

Comment: What do you think `cin.ignore()` does?

Comment: Also, please don't use [system("pause")](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html). It's dangerous, non-portable, and it marks you as someone who doesn't realize they're programming in C++.

Comment: Well, I'm currently learning C++ I've noticed that without the syste("Pause") for the programs I've created, the .exe file will not stay up long enough to show the results. Also, I know what the cin.ignore() function does, but after doing research on multiple sites, everyone stated to use the cin.ignore() after the cin >> and  without it I lose a whole word instead of the letter. That is where I'm stuck.

Comment: If you want to write terminal programs, learn how to launch a program from a terminal. If you want to write programs that launch from a GUI, learn how to write GUI programs. Don't bastardize your code just to permit it to be launched from a broken launcher that doesn't provide a proper terminal.

Comment: "*without it I lose a whole word instead of the letter*" -- This is a variant of "I don't understand what my program is doing". The solution is the universal one -- add logging and/or extra debugging to your program (or step through it with a debugger) until you do understand exactly what effect each line of code is actually having.

Comment: David, this is for a class and this is introductory C++. There is no need to bash me for learning, I understand what you are telling me and I will get to that point in the future, but right now I need to figure out the problem that I posted about.

Comment: That's no reason to ignore sound tangential advice in comments! :)

Comment: @Awkt I'm not bashing you for learning. I'm giving you advice on how to learn effectively. Getting help on a specific issue is great, but learning how to troubleshoot code that doesn't do what you expect is *much* more important.

Comment: Sorry about taking it the wrong way, and I understand and agree with what you just said. I currently understand my code to a degree, but I have a lot to learn and very appreciative of the advice and insight that have been provided to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will find this is caused by the cin.ignore() call.

the .ignore() of the istream base class functions by

> Extract[ing] characters from the input sequence and discard[ing] them

The default value is to discard One (1) character.

In short,

```
    cin >> cd_Name[x];
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, cd_Name[x]);
```

Will get the name inputted by the user, Ignore the first character, then extract the string to your array.

If you called cin.ignore(2) it would remove the first two characters, and so on.

[Please view this article for more information (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/)

[EDIT]
You may find your getline and ignore calls are arbitrary
try using this in your loop:
cin will deliver the resulting string directly into the variable given, you should not need getline, nor ignore to achieve this.

```
    char Name_tmp[50];
    char Artist_tmp[50];
    for (int x = 0; x < numCD; x++)
    {
        cout << "Enter name of CD " << x + 1 << ": ";
        cin.get(Name_tmp, 50); //get 50 character (max length of string) into string variable
        cout << "Enter the artist of " << cd_Name[x] << ": ";
        cin.get(Artist_tmp, 50); //get 20 character (max length of string) into string variable
        cout << endl;
        cd_Name[x] = Name_tmp;
        cd_Artist[x] = Artist_tmp;
    }//end of for loop
```

In short, I'm extracting a set number of characters (less can be taken, but no more) from the users input into a temporary C-string, then assigning those values into your array.

Note, I made use of the [istream::get](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) method.

[Edit 2]
I noticed David Schwartz's post as to the implementation of using

```
system ("pause");
```

Unfortunately, I believe David is an avid linux programmer, and is not familiar with Visual Studio - When a program in run from VS (unless done so without debugging) the program output window closes before you can view the results.
This may also occur with some other IDE's.

My recommendation is to use something like this instead

```
char tmp[20];
cin.get(tmp, 20);
return;
```

This will pause and wait for the user to provide some input (a return should count as input in the case of MS Visual Studio)

Comment: I've tried that earlier after doing some research on other sites, but when I remove get.ignore(), then the input display removes the whole first word rather than the first letter. For example, when I type in "The Battle of Los Angeles", it will only show "Battle of Los Angeles".

Comment: I can't see a reason why it would remove the first word in that case further, why are you using getline?
Let me post a snippit that may ease the problem

Comment: Well the reason why I was using getline was because the input that the user would put in would have spaces. So when I used cin >> cd_Name; when the user put in "The Battle of Los Angeles" it would only display "The" and then skip the 2nd question.

Comment: I've further updated to continue on @David Schwartz 's earlier statements about system pause.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much John for you help and explanation on both my code and the system ("pause"). Currently in the class I am taking my instructor wants us to use the system("pause") but I will remember this for the future when I begin to do true development work.

Comment: @Awkt , if this did solve your problem, I'd appreciate you marking it as a solution - I don't have much reputation here - thus I can't currently comment.

That said, I'm glad I was able to help you, I've learnt of many an instructor - often their reasons for using odd conventions (such as system pause) are more logical than they seem. Sometimes this is due to using older compilers (due to software) sometimes because 'it is how they where taught' - be aware of the "right way", but remember there's more than one "right way" depending on may factors :)